# Which gridview event is raised when the data returned by its DataSource varies?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview fed by a `SqlDataSource` that has a series of checkboxes as control parameters. Checking the controlbox changes the data displayed in the gridview.

What Gridview event is raised by any change in the set of the checkboxes?

If the data returned by the `SqlDataSource` changes, then this I thought would fire the `OnDataBound` event but it doesn't!

I could probably solve this by implementing an `OnClick` event in every single checkbox, but there must be a more elegant way based on the change of data that feeds the gridview.

Regards, Martin

Comment: RowDataBound instead of OnDataBound

Comment: Solved! My fault: the event I used was OnRowDataBound but the name I gave was OnDataBound. So, the OnDataBound event is correct one to use here. Martin